# VBA - clear thousands of cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to speed up a process. I have a spreadsheet which looks similar to the below:

I have the following data structure:

```
+-------------------+
| Excel Ranged Name |
+-------------------+
| Name1             |
| Name2             |
| Name3             |
| Name4             |
| Name5             |
| Name6             |
| Name7             |
| Name8             |
| Name9             |
| Name10            |
| Name11            |
+-------------------+
```

Where Name1, Name2 etc all represent actual ranged names on the spreadsheet. i.e. there is a cell named "Name1" etc.

I want to create a macro which will clear the contents of each of those named ranges. I can do this with a for-loop:

```
Sub cleartest()

For i = 1 To 35000
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(Cells(i, 1)).ClearContents
    End With
Next i




End Sub
```

However, as I have 35000 or so to clear, it takes 30-40 seconds for my PC. I am looking for a way to speed this up, if it is possible.

I have also disabled autocalcs, events etc.

Comment: No, it clears Range("Name1").clearcontent, then Range("Name2").clearcontents etc.

Comment: D'oh, I read it incorrectly, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps build a composite range with union() then clear that once, its the ClearContents that's expensive.

Comment: @AlexK. - That's what I was thinking.  Generally, would clearing a Union over looping through the ranges of that union be quicker?

Comment: I would think that the code that interacts less with the sheet would be faster but only testing would tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub t()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A3") ' this is the range where your named ranges are kept

Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In rng
    Range(cel.Value).ClearContents
Next cel

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this out now and get back to you. However, there are merged cells, how can these be dealt with? Can I ask how this would be faster as it is the same loop? Cheers

Comment: @user33484 - Primarily the screen updating, disabling events, and changing calculation to manual at the start should help cut down on time taken.

Comment: I'm also thinking you could create a Union of all named ranges, except I don't think that'd be any quicker to clear at once than the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a dictionary to gather all named ranges on their respective sheets and union them into a single range, and then loops through those sheets containing named ranges and clears their contents.  This should be very quick to execute for you:

**EDIT**: The macro will now only go through named ranges that exist in the specified list.

**EDIT 2**: The macro will now account for named ranges that have merged cells.

**EDIT 3**: The macro will now account for named ranges that have multiple areas of discontiguous range areas where one or more of those areas is a merged cell

**EDIT 4**: The macro now accounts for possible #REF errors from obsolete named ranges.

**EDIT 5**: The macro now accounts for sheets with spaces in their names.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsNamedRangeList As Worksheet
    Dim rNamedRangeList As Range
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim rTest As Range
    Dim aAreas As Variant
    Dim vArea As Variant
    Dim vName As Variant
    Dim vSheetNamesRange As Variant
    Dim hSheets As Object
    Dim sSheet As String
    Dim sRange As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsNamedRangeList = wb.Sheets("NamedRangeList")  'Change this to the actual name of the worksheet containing the list of named range names
    Set rNamedRangeList = wsNamedRangeList.Columns("A") 'Change this to the actual column containing the list of named range names
    Set hSheets = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each vName In wb.Names
        Set rTest = rNamedRangeList.Find(vName.Name, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
        If Not rTest Is Nothing Then
            aAreas = Split(vName, ",")
            For Each vArea In aAreas
                sSheet = Split(vArea, "!")(0)
                If Left(sSheet, 1) = "=" Then sSheet = Mid(sSheet, 2)
                If Left(sSheet, 1) = "'" Then sSheet = Mid(sSheet, 2, Len(sSheet) - 2)
                sRange = Split(vArea, "!")(1)
                If sSheet <> "#REF" And sRange <> "#REF" Then
                    Set rName = wb.Sheets(sSheet).Range(sRange)
                    If hSheets.Exists(sSheet) Then
                        Set hSheets(sSheet) = Union(hSheets(sSheet), rName.MergeArea)
                    Else
                        Set hSheets(sSheet) = rName.MergeArea
                    End If
                End If
            Next vArea
        End If
    Next vName

    For Each vSheetNamesRange In hSheets.Items
        vSheetNamesRange.ClearContents
    Next vSheetNamesRange

End Sub
```

Comment: This clears all ranged names no? I would just like a selected few

Comment: @user33484 Correct, this will clear all named ranges.  From your original question: ..."However, as I have 35000 or so to clear..."  and you don't specify that only want a selected few.  How are the selected few that you'd like to clear defined?  Do you have a list of those named range names?  Or perhaps they're limited to a single worksheet?

Comment: Sorry, the table in my question is just a snapshot. I get the ranged names I want to clear from this table, it has 35000 or so entries, so I would get a list of the named ranges by doing range("A1:A35000") for example.

Comment: @user33484 Ok, I see, you have a specific worksheet listing all of the specific named range names you want to have cleared.  I didn't take it quite that literally.  Easy enough to update the code, give me a minute.

Comment: @user33484 - you have a spreadsheet with over `35000` named ranges??

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes.

Comment: Just get a subscript out of range error running it as is. Not sure why, perhaps as there are merged cells? will try debug

Comment: @user33484 gah, merged cells are the worst, always try to avoid merged cells.  is there a specific reason you're using merged cells other than cosmetic?

Comment: @user33484 Also, if you're just running the code "as is" I'd expect you to get the subscript out of range error.  You need to update the sheet name and column letter for the NamedRangeList variables so it can find your list of named range names.

Comment: Thanks, it's still getting a subscript out of range. I can't debug it as it is linking to the correct range name but is somehow coming with this error. I have updated as per the instructions

Comment: @user33484 I updated the code again, give that another try, otherwise it would need to be refactored.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately, gets stuck on: Set rName = wb.Sheets(sSheet).Range(sRange). The cell it is referring to is a merged cell so it's getting out of range from that.

Comment: When you click on Debug, hover over `sSheet` and `sRange` and verify the sheet exists in your workbook and the range is correct (it might not include the merged cell range, that gets added in slightly later).  It sounds like the named range is referring to a sheet that no longer exists or a cell (or range of cells) that no longer exists, resulting in a `#REF!` error which can cause the error you're seeing.  This happens when a sheet or range of cells that contained named ranges gets deleted.  I'll put in a check for valid references

Comment: I don't think it's that. I think it's because when you are getting the sheet and cell, the sheet has single quotes around it. E.g. if the sheetname was ExampeName, it would return 'ExampleName', and this throws up the error

Comment: Got it working after fixing that but unfortunately it is the same speed! Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user33484 Ahh, ok, your sheets have spaces in their names.  Glad to hear you got it working.  I am sorry to hear it's the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub t()
On Error GoTo exitErr
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A3") ' this is the range where your named ranges are kept

Dim nmRng As Range, cel As Range

For Each cel In rng
    Range(cel.Value).ClearContents
Next cel

ExitErr:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

@BruceWayne -  Error handling PLEASE.  Why is this so important??  What happens if one of the ranges in the list aren't present?  Your code breaks, Screen Updating is left off, Events don't trigger, and your formulas stop calculating since they were switched off and never turned back on.

Answer (score 1):

Call ClearNamedRanges with the range of names that you want to clear

This goes through all named ranges in the active workbook and clears content if it finds the name in the provided range.

Edit: I believe Application.Match might work faster than Range.Find Test both let me know.

```
Sub Test()
    Call ClearNamedRanges(Sheet1.Range("A1:A35000"))
End Sub

Private Sub ClearNamedRanges(ByRef oNameRange As Range)

    Dim oName As Name
    For Each oName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        'if Not IsError(Application.Match(oName.Name, oNameRange, 0)) Then oName.RefersToRange.ClearContents
        If Not oNameRange.Find(oName.Name) Is Nothing Then oName.RefersToRange.ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to see if this would at all be faster. Instead of accessing the sheet twice, `.Range` and `Cells`, I loop through an array so there's only one sheet reference in the loop.

```
Sub cleartest()

    Dim RangeNames() as Variant

    RangeNames = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A35000").value
    For i = 1 To 35000
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range(RangeNames(i,1)).ClearContents
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Something else to try might be using `.Range(RangeNames(i,1)).Value = vbNullString` if you just wanted to clear the values. I don't think that it would clear any formatting though.

Answer (score 0):

you could try managing not empty "objects" (cells with named range name and named ranges themselves) only

```
Sub clear()
    Dim namedRangeCells As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' reference your sheet
        Set namedRangeCells = .Cells(1, 1) ' set namedRangeCells to a cell you don't care about
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop thropugh referenced sheet column A not empty cells
            Set namedRangeCells = Union(namedRangeCells, .Range(cell.Value)) ' collect named ranges
        Next
    End With

    namedRangeCells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents ' clear collected named ranges with with not empty value
End Sub
```